# Accessing first element of stdobject

Tags: php, json

I am using an API where I get the following response:

```
{"BTC_LTC":{"last":"0.0251","lowestAsk":"0.02589999","highestBid":"0.0251","percentChange":"0.02390438",
"baseVolume":"6.16485315","quoteVolume":"245.82513926"},"BTC_NXT":{"last":"0.00005730","lowestAsk":"0.00005710",
"highestBid":"0.00004903","percentChange":"0.16701570","baseVolume":"0.45347489","quoteVolume":"9094"}, ... }
```

It is no problem to access the object when I would know the key like

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$result->BTC_LTC->last
```

In my case I do not know the XXX_XXX keys. How can I get the keys? I tried things like $result->{0} / $result->[0] / $result{0} / $result[0] without success.

How can I retrieve the values of XXX_XXX (e.g. in the example above BTC_LTC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php

$json = '{"BTC_LTC":{"last":"0.0251","lowestAsk":"0.02589999","highestBid":"0.0251","percentChange":"0.02390438",
"baseVolume":"6.16485315","quoteVolume":"245.82513926"},"BTC_NXT":{"last":"0.00005730","lowestAsk":"0.00005710",
"highestBid":"0.00004903","percentChange":"0.16701570","baseVolume":"0.45347489","quoteVolume":"9094"}}';

$result = json_decode($json);
$vars = get_object_vars($result);
$keys = array_keys($vars); 


echo $vars[$keys[0]]->last;

?>
```

You can try the code [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a foreach loop that should work

```
foreach($result as $k=>$v)
{
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `json_decode` allows specifying that you want an array returned:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
```

Now that result is an array you can use it as usual (looping, array_keys, e.t.c.).